# Namespace errors in Xaml and the application run perfectly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I know that there a lot of questions about this problem. but any of the answers solved me it:
I use VisualStudio 2013. I have a sulation with a Wpf project.
I create for example a public class, and I want to define a data template for this type in Xaml code so I add a reference to the viewModel directory-
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels"
then I add a dataTemplate 
.
I get an error:
The name "MainViewModel" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels"
I try all the sulations: rebuild it, restart VisualStudio, delete the suo file, debug it in AnyCpu and then switch it back to X64. 
I try to delete this row, and when I begin to write it, this row is completed auto, so I havn't spelling mistakes.
But although all, I get this error (for all the xaml references to files in my project), **it run perfectly, but the errors list isn't empty and I can't give it up.**
What else can I do? it looks like a bug in the Visual studio or something like that.
(I can't move the project to a local disk because we use a network disk)

Comment: "What else can I do?" Ignore the error? You could also try to disable the designer: http://blog.spinthemoose.com/2013/03/24/disable-the-xaml-designer-in-visual-studio/.

Comment: Can you show some xaml and code? maybe there is a problem in the constructor of the ViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, but I knew someone who had a similar problem and believe me, it is probably something simple, you're just not seeing it ;).


**Scenario**  (yes, I could be wrong)
You created youre 'class' but since then, you had build errors, so you're code has never compiled with the newly created class. Your Intellisense tells you the class does not exist, while in youre eyes it does.. **You're designer needs the compiled dll in order to include the classes in the namespace**. So you have  to find the bug in you're code and fix it => Compile it => Reload Designer and you're errors should be gone.

As an idea, can you post you're **Build Output** if this is not the solution?
**Note**
The reason why you would be able to 'run' youre code is because you could have a previous compiled .exe in you're output directory (you changed you're build from 32 to 64 bits, so you're output folder also changed)